# Last month's balance value to current month's opening balance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query which returns total balance(debit-credit) grouped by months. Have 4 columns;

1. ID
2. Month
3. Closing Balance
4. Opening Balance

What i want to do is to get last month's balance value into current month's opening balance value. For example; let's say February's closing balance value is 100.000$. Then March's opening value has to be 100.000$ too.

Sorry about styling. I am so bad about it. Here is the sample data.
[image: Here is the sample data.]

I want  **-14.830.707,59** values on March's  **OPEN_BALANCE** cells.

Comment: please share your row data, so we can try

Answer (score 0):

Without a table schema, example data, or desired results... Something like this:

Using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [**`outer apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
;with cte (
  select
      Id
    , MonthDate = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Date]), 0) /* date datatype */
    , ClosingBalance = sum(debit)-sum(credit)
  from t
  group by 
      Id
    , dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Date]), 0)
)
select
    Id
  , MonthDate
  , Month = datename(month, MonthDate) 
  , ClosingBalance 
  , OpeningBalance = x.OpeningBalance
from cte
  outer apply (
    select top 1
      OpeningBalance = i.ClosingBalance
    from cte as i
    where i.Id = cte.Id
      and i.MonthDate < cte.MonthDate
    order by i.MonthDate desc
  ) as x
```

Using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and a `left join`:

```
;with cte (
  select
      Id
    , MonthDate = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Date]), 0) /* date datatype */
    , ClosingBalance = sum(debit)-sum(credit)
    , rn = row_number() over (
        partition by Id 
        order by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Date]), 0)
        )
  from t
  group by 
      Id
    , dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [Date]), 0)
)
select
    cte.Id
  , cte.MonthDate
  , Month = datename(month, cte.MonthDate) 
  , cte.ClosingBalance 
  , OpeningBalance = i.ClosingBalance
from cte
  left join cte as x
    on x.Id = cte.Id
      and x.rn = cte.rn-1
```